# Send Keyboard presses via IP HTTP GET

Tags: android, http, iptv

I have an IPTV Android BOX (ATN 200II) and unfortunately have no IR control on a control system. They have no API to control the app remotely, but the remote just sends keyboard presses to the device. I was just wonder is there any way that I can build a Driver that will send a HTTP GET Request (or maybe post) that will emulate a keyboard button on the Android box.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By my experience working in IPTV, Remote Control for windows also works in linux, so my IPTV company ODM it's own define remote keypad. receive key events through USB interface as windows did.

[image: usb keypad]

Via webview js interface, keypad control device system set-top box linux and send dump key to commercial TV for hotel is also possible.